# Running code synchronously through loop

Tags: javascript, synchronization

I want to execute my code synchronously with some wait in the loop.
First one, on onCreate function(), every loop will executed every 3 seconds.

than onInflate() function will executed after onCreate function done.

I've reading many question on SO. I've do like this code bellow

```
var onCreate = function(){ 
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    for(var i = 0; i < TOTAL_FRAME; i++){
        scene.set(i, {iFrame : "#iviFrame" + (i+1)} ); 

        $(scene.get(i).iFrame).attr("src", buffer.get(i).url); 
        // Wait for 3 second every loop
    } 
    deferred.resolve("done");                
    return deferred.promise();  
}
```

and then wait for onCreate function done

```
onCreate().done(function(){
    onInflate();   

    console.log("XXX2"); 
});
```

I've tried this code bellow but doesn't work.

```
var onCreate = function(){ 
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function () {
        scene.set(x, {iFrame : "#iviFrame" + (x+1)} );
        $(scene.get(x).iFrame).attr("src", buffer.get(x).url); 
        x++;   

        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("XXX1B");
            scene.set(x, {iFrame : "#iviFrame" + (x+1)} );
            $(scene.get(x).iFrame).attr("src", buffer.get(x).url); 

            deferred.resolve("done");                
            return deferred.promise();                        
        }, 3000);
    }, 3000);

    deferred.resolve("done");                
    return deferred.promise();  
}
```

The flow should be  
-- onCreate(){
-- -- loop
-- -- Task x
== == Wait 3S
-- -- end loop
-- }

-- onInflate()

How to running synchronously with some wait?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using standard promises and to read up on [Promises and Callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in general.

```js
var onCreate = function() {
  var deferred = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var computations = 0;

    function compute() {
      var d = Date.now();
      //do 1/60 of a second worth of calculations
      while (Date.now() - d < 16) {
        computations++;
      }
    }
    //Wait 3 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("TIMEOUT EXPIRED");
      //Do some computation
      compute();
      //Resolve promise
      resolve(computations);
    }, 3000);
  });
  return deferred;
};
//TEST
console.log("START");
onCreate().then((function(computations) {
  console.log("Hey there.\nSo.. i just did " + computations + " calculations and i was wondering..\nDid i do a good job? O_o");
}));
console.log("END");
```

**EDIT 1 - Asynchronous Promise pattern**

For asynchronous Promises, define a computation function ("timeoutOperation") that does some calculation and tests for some condition. If condition met, resolve promise, else, call itself to perform another calculation.

Below is an example of this pattern which describes an asynchronous  `for...loop` pattern:

```js
var onCreate = function() {
  var deferred = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var timeoutTime = 100;
    var computations = 30;
    var i = 0;
    //Operation to handle computation and set new timeouts until condition met
    function timeoutOperation() {
      console.log("TIMEOUT " + i + " EXPIRED");
      //Do some computation
      /* COMPUTATION HERE */
      //Append i and test
      i++;
      if (i < computations) {
        setTimeout(timeoutOperation, timeoutTime);
      } else {
        //Resolve promise
        resolve("Some return value");
      }
    }
    setTimeout(timeoutOperation, timeoutTime);
  });
  return deferred;
};
//TEST
console.log("START");
onCreate().then((function(return_value) {
  console.log(return_value);
}));
console.log("END");
```

I lowered the amount of loops to `30` ("computations") and the delay to `100` ("timeoutTime") for the sake of example.

Comment: If you look my code above, i need to do loop from i = 0 to TOTAL_FRAME which is every cycle loop I need wait for 3 Second. If I don't wrong, your code only provide a delay 3 second before compute() function execute. What I need on compute() while loop, I need every loop delay for 3 second. Any idea?